# Xcode Removing Parse From Project -- Xcode MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h does not exist Error

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm removing Parse frameworks from my project in Xcode, after I deleted Bridging Header.h file and all other parse references. I got this error

Xcode MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the value for the bringing header under Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Objective-C Bridging Header:

[image: xcode]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get rid of this error.

Clear the value in here.

Targets > [Your App Target] > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Objective-C Bridging Header:

I was able to compile the project after clear the value. Hope this will help others too.